# mongoose: create new element in X collection, update another in Y collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to develop a CRUD app for users to store, add, delete and update recipes. It's built on MEVN stack. As I need to show the user, which recipes they have created, I am trying to create a recipe based on this model:

```
const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Title of the recipe is required'],
    },
    category: {
        type: Array,
        required: [true, 'Category is required'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Description is required'],
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Image is required'],
    },
    ingredients: {
        type: Array,
        required: [true, 'Ingredients are required'],
    },
    timeOfPreparation: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    preparation: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sourceName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sourceUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);

module.exports = Recipe;
```

And at the same time update User model, based on this:

```
const UserSchema = Schema({
    googleId: String,
    name: String,
    favorites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }],
    authoredRecipes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }],
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

In the controller, I have this method (as per @Stock Overflaw comment):

```
exports.create_new_recipe = (req, res, next) => {
Recipe.create(req.body)
    .then(recipe => {
        User.update(
            { _id: req.body.author },
            {
                $push: { authoredRecipes: recipe.id },
            }
        );
        res.send(res.status);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ error });
    });
```

};

This method is called when I go to /create endpoint. However, even though I do get all the correct ids (req.body.author and recipe.id), I cannot get this to work. In my mLab recipe collection the recipe is displayed correctly (all data that I have inserted with authorId), however in the User collection, the array of authoredRecipes stays empty.

How can I get mongoose to both create an object in one collection as well as update another object based on their ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) for `findByIdAndUpdate` requires the `_id` field as its value, not an object:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.author, {
  $push: { authoredRecipes: recipe.id }
});
// equivalent to the more general method:
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.author }, {
  $push: { authoredRecipes: recipe.id }
});
// and if you don't need the modified document in your callback, this should be faster:
// EDIT: this is advised against (we should use a user object, not the collection)
User.update({ _id: req.body.author }, { // or updateOne
  $push: { authoredRecipes: recipe.id }
});
```

#### Edit: a working, minimal example

Mind `{new: true}` maybe? Depending on how you test whether it works...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');

const userIdFile = './tmp.txt'; // just for this test

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meuh', {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // removes a deprecation warning
  useFindAndModify: false // removes another deprecation warning
});

// make schemas/models
const RecipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String }
});
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String },
  data: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe' }]
});
const RecipeModel = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// user precreation
// UserModel.create({
//   name: 'me, myself and I'
// }).then((user) => {
//   fs.writeFile(userIdFile, user.id, console.log.bind(null, 'error writing file:'));
//   mongoose.connection.close();
// });
// return;

// fetch user
const userId = fs.readFileSync(userIdFile);

let pushedRecipeId; // to test everything went smooth
RecipeModel.create({
  title: 'pasta solo'
}).then((recipe) => {
  console.log('created recipe:', recipe);
  pushedRecipeId = recipe.id;
  return UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userId },
    { $push: { data: recipe.id } },
    { new: true } // forces callback to be passed a fresh object
  );
}).then((user) => {
  console.log('updated user:', user);
  console.log('izok:', !!~user.data.indexOf(pushedRecipeId));
  mongoose.connection.close();
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
  mongoose.connection.close();
})
```

Example output I got:

```sh
# creating user (uncommented this part)
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/web/test$ node .
error writing file: null
# calling for $push (re-commented user creation)
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/web/test$ node .
created recipe: { _id: 5c72be7032bd2f1acad37c95, title: 'pasta solo', __v: 0 }
updated user: { data: [ 5c72be7032bd2f1acad37c95 ],
  _id: 5c72be6a8143fd1aa9416d85,
  name: 'me, myself and I',
  __v: 0 }
izok: true
# again $push
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/web/test$ node .
created recipe: { _id: 5c72c020c2ac7a1b8c65fa36, title: 'pasta solo', __v: 0 }
updated user: { data: [ 5c72be7032bd2f1acad37c95, 5c72c020c2ac7a1b8c65fa36 ],
  _id: 5c72be6a8143fd1aa9416d85,
  name: 'me, myself and I',
  __v: 0 }
izok: true
# and again
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/web/test$ node .
created recipe: { _id: 5c72c023bf62331b97ef096b, title: 'pasta solo', __v: 0 }
updated user: { data: 
   [ 5c72be7032bd2f1acad37c95,
     5c72c020c2ac7a1b8c65fa36,
     5c72c023bf62331b97ef096b ],
  _id: 5c72be6a8143fd1aa9416d85,
  name: 'me, myself and I',
  __v: 0 }
izok: true
# end
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/web/test$
```

I don't see what's wrong in your code, but at least you have something to compare with... hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue, I still don't receive any recipeId in authoredRecipes array

Comment: @llievredemars I updated with an example, hopefully you can find out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I inserted {new: true} and this has fixed the issue! And I appreciate a lot the fact that you took time to try to debug this :) Have an awesome day!

Comment: Good thing! But it means you weren't fully testing that the array was empty: it was only empty (actually: one step late every time) in your callback, yet the DB had stored it. ;)